# Unable to copy file to server on build. Access to path is denied

Tags: visual-studio

I have a solution in Visual Studio that is comprised of 5 projects. The projects build to assemblies (.dll). I have the output path of each project set to \my-web-server\wwwroot\bin, which works fine on one project. In the properties for all of my projects, I have the output path set to the same directory, but when I try building all but one of the projects, I get the error:

Unable to copy file "obj\Release\Index.dll" to "\my-web-server\wwwroot\bin\Index.dll". Access to the path '\my-web-server\wwwroot\bin\Index.dll' is denied.

I assume it could be an issue with permissions, because my organization keeps things locked down, but I have no control over granting permissions. Any help in the right direction is much appreciated.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

It must've been something silly. I deleted the .dll manually, then rebuilt. Looks like everything's working normally. Thanks.

Comment: +1 If the next person can run a SysInternals tool BEFORE DELETING THE FILE to see what is causing the Access Denied (ie a lock on the file) and report the root cause that would be much appreciated.

Comment: Running SysInternals procexp: devenv.exe sitting on the file. Unloading project didn't work but after closing solution I could delete System.Web.WebPages.Deployment.dll from bin. Eh.

Comment: perfect!! working fine after deleting the all the files in bin folder and built it.

Answer (score 3):

The solution for me was to delete everything in bin and obj folders in every project. Just ran this powershell script as described [here](http://blog.slaven.net.au/2006/11/22/use-powershell-to-delete-all-bin-obj-folders/).

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue.  A copy of Visual Studio (devenv.exe) was still running invisible in the background keeping the particular dll locked.

Answer (score 3):

Delete all DLLs from the bin folder and build the solution.

Answer (score 2):

just had the same issue, built a new project/solution, got it all working and then added to TFS.

Unfortunately I did not clean the build before adding and this meant some files that should not have been under source control were and were then read only(not checked out).
Manually deleting the files before rebuilding fixed the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely a program is running using that library.

This happens to me when running something to debug, and I forget to close it (not attached to IDE debugger).

And since this looks like a website, it is potentially due to the website being hosted from the development build folder, and someone is accessing it.

Comment: I can't think of anything else that could be accessing the file. I even stopped the web site in IIS, then tried building while stopped. No go.

Answer (score 0):

Similar to what [Aequitarum said](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1923543/unable-to-copy-file-to-server-on-build-access-to-path-is-denied/1923566#1923566), it's mostly likely a locked file because it's in use.  Since you have multiple projects, you mostly likely have references between them.  And since you have all the projects outputting to the same folder any of the referenced projects will most likely get copied more than once if you have those files set to be deployed in the child project. (In a C# web application, you can view the properties of the reference and look at the "Copy Local" property.)  And if you have the MsBuild project set to use multiple processors for the build, two child projects are both trying to copy the file at approximately the same time and one is erring out.

It's a very unique situation, but it is possible.

Answer (score 0):

***Working solution***

Just go to Task Manager and search Detail (if its Win10) and search with your application name (for easy search just look at your windows user id wise)

And right click shows properties. just give the permission like Administrator access.

That's all its working fine for me. ( I was struggling for 1 week and its killed more my time)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like WSearch Service locks up the files and does not release them.  I disabled the service on WINDOWS 10 and was able to rebuild the solution.